# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning in mongoose modal

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, promise

Here is what my controller looks like

```
exports.pnumber = async(function* (req, res) {
  const user = new User()
  try {
    yield user.findOneAndUpdate(req.body.pnumber, req.body.uid)
    res.send('success')
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
})
```

and my modal is

```
  findByIdAndUpdate: function (pnumber, uid) {
    var query = {'_id': uid},
      update = {
        $push: {pnumbers: pnumber}
      },
      options = {upsert: true}
    return UserSchema.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options)
  },
```

and the schema definition is

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, default: '' },
  pnumbers: [],
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
})
```

The error I am getting is

https://pastebin.com/ha65Jizm

Comment: The fact it's an unhandled promise rejection doesn't change the error source: `user is not defined` - you didn't define a `user` variable.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum still getting the error even after I fixed, see my edit.

Comment: There is no way you're getting that exact error with the above code, it's simply impossible. Copy the new error - and in the future please read error messages more carefully.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum yes you're right. I am trying different methods. now the error is https://pastebin.com/ha65Jizm

Comment: In any case, the error is about your mongoose usage and doesn't have much to do with promises - you're passing data to mongoose incorrectly. The unhandledRejection is just an "uncaught error"

Comment: Figured it out. Will be posting the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I was saving the wrong object. Managed to fix this with

```
  findOdUpdate: function (pnumber, uid) {
    const User = mongoose.model('User')
    var query = {'_id': uid},
      update = {
        $push: {pnumbers: pnumber}
      },
      options = {upsert: true}
    return User.update(query, update, options)
  },
```

Answer (score -1):

Use after findOneAndUpdate .catch((err)=>{}) to catch any errors occurring, As you are using async you can use within try block use await instead of yield.
Error You are facing is 'user is not defined.' i.e. the variable you are using as

```
user.findByIdAndUpdate(req.body.pnumber, req.body.uid)
```

here user is not a model. before this type:

```
const user = mongoose.model('user',UserSchema)
```

Comment: Error is still there, I tried the `. catch `, `await ` and defined user.